# Apache Can't Start again after restart

Tags: apache, service, centos7, httpd.conf

I'm confused because of this error. Any help will be appreciated

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include all relevant information about the failure in the body of the question. External links will eventually rot, making this question less useful over time. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "top" command to see if any apache service works. If is, kill all and then do service apache2 reload, and service apache2 start. Paste your top results here.

Comment: There are so many tasks there are 124 tasks, which one should I kill?

Comment: Kill Apache using the `pkill -9 httpd` command and start it again `systemctl restart httpd`.

If it doesn't work, please post the output of `journalctl -xn`.